# Disable queries being run by pgadmin backend

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I would like to know where i can disable queries that pgadmin generates and runs by itself in the background. An example of a query is below

```
select oid,pg_catalog.format_type(oid,NULL) as typename 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type 
WHERE oid IN (1043,1042) 
ORDER BY oid;
```

If they cannot be disabled can I at least stop them from appearing in the logs?

Comment: You'll probably won't be able to disable these queries as they are used to show the data type of your columns and Pgadmin needs them to get the relation between the pg_type `oid` and the human-readable name.

Comment: What's the problem with those queries? Every SQL client that displays information about table metadata will have queries like that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the queries, I just want the queries not to appear in postgres logs. I just want to exclude the pgadmin generated queries from appearing in the logs

Comment: Why are they appearing in the logs in the first place?  You must have some non-default setting to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

You must have changed the default logging level using config changes. Please check - https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8